# Finding num values, and min/ max values in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I am struggling with this code. I need to write a program that reads in an arbitrary number of data points from standard input. Then it returns the number of values, the min/max, and average value. I have not made much progress but here is all i have. Thanks in advance for help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    double num,sum=0,min,max;
    max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int Date=0;
    while (input.hasNext()) {
         num=input.nextDouble();
            sum+=num;
            Date++;
            if(num>=max)

            {
             max=num;
             System.out.println(max);
            }
           if(num<min)
            {
             min=num; 
             System.out.println(min);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: which portion of your code is evaluating min/max/avg?

Comment: Condition in while loop should be input.hasNext ()

Answer (score 1):

Create local variables and initialize them like:

```
int count;
double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
double sum = 0;
```

Whenever you read a double value from input, do it like:

```
count++; 

if (d<min) min = d;
if (d>max) max = d;

sum += d;
```

Finally

```
double average = sum / count;
```

Comment: Thanks! I am gonna use input from another program that measures weather info, so how do I do this for the time measures as well? I need to measure, Date, time, and values.

Comment: Change a typo error, should assign Double.MAX_VALUE , MIN_Value but not Integer.

Comment: Looks like you are doing this for an assignment. Is it a Java programming assignment or something else? If not a programming assignment, you have many easy ways to get the result. You may try Excel which is simple.

Back to the programming, the input from another program is from a text file right?  Are you going to get the max/min/avg just for values? What is "measure" mean?

Comment: Yeah it is, I am gonna get the min/max/ avg values for different aspects of the program, ex: date, time, and the total number of values included in those two.

Comment: Get each line as String, use String.split to split it into different strings seperated by spaces or other characters as applicable. Then use Double.parseDouble(String) to get the double value, and DateFormat to parse the date and time.

Comment: Could you show me an example of using a `Double.parseDouble(String)` for this case? I am lost

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Assignment4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double num,sum=0,min,max;
        max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int count=0;
        while (input.hasNext()) {
                num=input.nextInt();
                sum+=num;
                count++;
                if(num>=max)
                {
                 max=num;
                }
               if(num<min)
                {
                 min=num; 
                }
        }
        double avg=sum/count;
        System.out.println("The Average of Numbers is:"+avg);
        }

}
```

Comment: How would I add the date variable I am measuring the min/max and avg for?

Comment: date variable is to take input from user?
 num=input.nextInt(); change it to
 num=input.nextDouble();
It takes input from user

Comment: Thanks. inorder to get the min/max/avg values for time as well I would just do a similar thing?

Comment: I need to date to be a String not int, how do I change that